# Trying to manage arrays Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python, and was looking to try to learn how to allocate new elements to an array, however I keep getting errors.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\py\test.py", line 33, in
>   
>       main()   File "F:\py\test.py", line 19, in main
>       for i in range(0,num): TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I have never touched python before this, and have only worked with C++. I know in c++ that creating a dynamic array would be as follows:

```
...
int * newarray = new int[];
for(i=0; i>myVariable; i++)
newarray[i] = ...
...
```

However I am having a bit of trouble. Is there anyone willing to give me some advice, or a reference I could look at to better understand how to work with arrays? Thanks. 
Python code is below:

```
import math
def angles(function,ang, angle):
    i=0
    for i in range(i, ang - 1):
        angle1[i] = angle[i]
        if function == "sin":
            angle1[i] = math.sin(ang[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            return angel1
    return angel1

def main():
    num = input("Enter how many Angles you want to solve for: ")
    angle = []
    for item in angle:
        angle = [num]
    for i in range(0,num):
        i = 0
        angle[i] = input("Enter angles: ")
        i+=1
    type1 = input("Enter the function you want to solve for")
    angleanswers[num] = angles(type1, num, angle)
    print("The answers are: ")

    for i in range(0, num):
        print(angleanswers[i])
        i+=1
        if i == num:
            break
    return 0
main()
```

Comment: instead of num=input() ,do num=int(input()) and also angle[i] will not work you have to use angle.append

Answer (score 0):

your `num` variable is of string type which cannot be used as an array index. Type cast it to an int

```
num = int(input("Enter how many Angles you want to solve for: "))
```

Comment: Ah! I see, so it automatically assumes it to be of string datatype unless specified?

Comment: yes in python 3.x,  by default your input variable is of str type. You have to type cast it to appropriate type

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you need to learn a bit about list methods.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

For example 'append'

```
>>> myvar1 = 10
>>> myvar2 = 11
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist.append(myvar1)
>>> mylist.append(myvar2)
>>> print(mylist)
```

The output would be

```
>>> [10,11]
```

If you want to append new elements to the array from user input then:

```
#int, float, str, etc. depending on what you want
new_element = int(input("Enter data"))
mylist.append(new_element)
```